# Adding components to stage at runtime

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to ape the MS Paint application in Flash. I have a small point that I want to get cleared. I want to set the thickness of the line that I am drawing.

I want to add a numeric stepper to stage dynamically. Only when I click on option to draw line the numeric stepper must appear on stage. It must be removed when I select another component.

How can I add it at runtime. I got tutorials and references in which the stepper is always there on the stage. But I want it only when I want to draw the line.

Thanks and Regards

Bobby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the `addChild` and `removeChild` methods of the `DisplayObjectContainer` class.

If you're using Flex then you might want to look at `PopUpManager` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use the property `.visible` available on any `DisplayObject`...